(Unity, C#) What is the most efficient way to specify an integer value to pass an instantiated button/canvas when it is created?
I would like to build a tree-like structure for my game.
This should happen by itself as it would be quite complicated
to develop individual cards manually.
To implement this I would like to use the Unity UI Toolkit,
However, is there a useful way how I can give the instantiated [instantiate()] clone the required data?
The prefab looks like this:
-Canvas
- button
- Text1
- Text2
The canvas (or the button) needs the ID of the card from the database, the Textfield needs the name.
The next level is then built from the cards that have entered the CardID as ParentID.
What's the best way to hand this over?
At first I tried to do it manually, which of course is stupid. I also considered putting the ID in the name of the button
to install, but then I have to disassemble it when I need it, which is probably quite inefficient.
The question is not about how I read the data from the database, but rather how I store it in the appropriate clone so that it can represent a specific card.
Best regards
Tobias

You put a dedicated component (MonoBehaviour) on the root of your prefab and have a proper method to populate it with data, callbacks etc. That component has (serialized) references to all your nested components you want to initialize ...

I understand you have some entity with the data you need to pass. If it is correct, you can make a prefab from your structure and instantiate it anytime you need to by using UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(yourPrototype).
Then, you can create some root script with any internal logic you want. Let it be just passing the corresponding data to the text fields to simplify the example (assume you are using textmeshpro label):
public class MyAwesomeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TextMeshProUGUI _myTextField;

    public void SetData(string text)
    {
        _myTextField.text = text;
    }
}

// any other place. I assume that you have some prototype of the object with the MyAwesomeScript attached to it
...
MyAwesomeScript script = Instantiate(_protitype).GetComponent<MyAwesomeScript>();

//It will be helpful to check if your script is not null
script.SetData("my custom text for the label");
...

So, what's going on above:

you create the script with the serialized field
you can set any link inside the prefab to this field in the inspector. Any clone of this prefab will guarantee that the link will be valid
you provide a public method to operate with the internal structure

So, the same can be done for internal object behavior like button clicks, label texts, any internal validations, etc.

Thanks for your answer :)
So if I write a similar script, I add it to the canvas, for example. The canvas has a button and this button in turn has two text fields. The script then says:
the data (integer for CardID and string for CardName).
If I need this data later I just have to access the script that is available in the clone.
Did I understand that correctly?

Actually not. You mix several things. There is data and visualization. My understanding was that you need help with how to visualize your data. From your comment, I see that you want to use your visualization as a data - it can be done, yes, but it is a bad practice.

In my mind you have some collection of data for all of your cards. And a card (or set of cards, it doesn't matter). At some moment (for example, after the user clicks some button), you need to set up your card for new data. Then my example will fit.

Oh. Well all I want is to give the CardID and CardName entries from the database to the button/canvas, so it knows what it is. In the case of the CardName, it will also be displayed.
I use the CardID to build the rest of the structure.
How else would you do it?
If you think it's bad practice, I'll believe you because I don't have much experience. But it has to be possible somehow to tell a button which player's card it belongs to without bad practice?

The question is about "if I need this data later." In my mind, it would be much better to use the data from your data layer rather than your card script. However, it depends highly on the situation and your project structure. If we are talking about "how to transfer the data to corresponding fields" - the principle is the same as in the example above.

I don't really have a data layer, apart from the database. Of course I could also get all the data from each player's card and save it. But then I still have the problem that the map (the clone of the prefab) needs the data to display it.
As I understand you, I should create a data layer where all the information is stored. From there I just get the information one after the other because I have to build the structure from top to bottom.
I think if I understood you correctly this time, I'll just implement it and see how it goes. Thanks for your help and patience :)
